# Selecting a frameset with index in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im currently in the phase of learning selenium with python.

Following is the code im trying to run:

```
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com')
#print browser.page_source

elems=browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('frameset')
browser.switch_to_frame(elems[1])
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[class='input_password']").send_keys('123456789'+Keys.ENTER)
```

However Im unable to do so and ends up in an error.
Following is the error i see

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/abhishek/PycharmProjects/Selenium/01_Selenium.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abhishek/PycharmProjects/Selenium/01_Selenium.py", line 115, in <module>
    browser.switch_to_frame(elems[1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 537, in switch_to_frame
    self._switch_to.frame(frame_reference)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/switch_to.py", line 67, in frame
    self._driver.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_FRAME, {'id': frame_reference})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: Element is not a frame element: FRAMESET
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.switchToFrame (file:///tmp/tmpbrHNVJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10783)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpbrHNVJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12614)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpbrHNVJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12619)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpbrHNVJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12561)
```

Following is the pagesource:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/abhishek/PycharmProjects/Selenium/01_Selenium.py
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<title>Welcome to HDFC Bank NetBanking</title>
<script language="javascript">
    var daemon          = 'NETBANKING';
    var p_remoteaddress = '';
    var RsaAuthReq      = '';

    var l_path = window.location.pathname;

    if(l_path == undefined || l_path == '' || l_path.indexOf("/netbanking") &lt; 0){
        window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host +"/netbanking";
    }

</script>
</head>
    <frameset cols="*" rows="*" framespacing="0" frameborder="O" border="false">
        <frameset cols="*" rows="*,30" framespacing="0" frameborder="O" border="false">
            <frame scrolling="yes" noresize="true" src="RSLogin.html?v=2" name="login_page" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" />
            <frame scrolling="no" noresize="true" src="footer.html" name="footer" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" />
        </frameset>
    </frameset>

</html>
```

Following are my doubts:

1. What is the python alternative to Java's
   browser.swichTo().Frame(int arg0) ?
2. Is the way of storing the webelements in a variable and using indexes to retrieve the required value a correct approach?

Kindly advice,
Thanks!

Comment: what error does it give you? also, use `browser.find_element_by_css_selector` instead of `By.CSS_SELECTOR`

Comment: @n1c9 Ive added the error in the main description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the python alternative to Java's browser.swichTo().Frame(int arg0) ?

This is quite similar in Python:

```
number = 0  # first frame
browser.switch_to.frame(number)
```

> Is the way of storing the webelements in a variable and using indexes to retrieve the required value a correct approach?

Yes, it could've worked in case the elements inside `elems` would be the `frame` elements.

In this case, you can do the following:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(0)
```

or:

```
browser.switch_to.frame("login_page")
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe !
Following doubts:

1. Can you explain why 0th index worked over here when as per the page source the login page falls under the second(1st index) frameset.

2. can any unique identifier be used as a frame reference in switch_to.frame?

Comment: @abhisheknair the frame containing the login field is the first frame element on the page and indexing starts with 0..you can use 4 things in `browser.switch_to.frame(...)`: `name`, `id`, index and the WebElement instance you've previously located. The last one - is what you were trying to do, but instead of `frameset`s, you should've located the `frame` elements..hope that makes things clearer..

Comment: Thanks again @alecxe !! :)